# CSS text-indent combined with white-space

Tags: css, text-indent

I have the following style already: `white-space: pre-wrap;`

This allows newlines to be treated as newlines (and spaces don't get collapsed) for the element.

Now I want to apply `text-indent: -40px; padding-left: 40px;` in an attempt to produce something like this:

```
This is a long line of text (or at least, just pretend it is) so it  
        will indent when it wraps.
Further lines of text appear as normal, but again if they exceed the
        maximum width then they wrap and indent.
```

Unfortunately, it's not doing quite what I intended:

```
This is a long line of text (or at least, just pretend it is) so it
        will indent when it wraps.
        Further lines of text appear as normal, but again if they
        exceed the maximum width then they wrap and indent.
```

Is there a way in CSS to indent wrapped lines, but counting newlines as a new first line?

Comment: Works fine for me if the newlines are represented as separate elements.  http://jsfiddle.net/gNVgQ/

Comment: @jessegavin But they're not, that's the whole point of `white-space: pre-wrap`.

Comment: Could you wrap each line in a `<div>`? Then you could use `text-indent` and `padding-left`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `text-indent` relates to the first line of an element, and newlines generated by line wrapping do not create elements. So instead of just newlines in HTML source, you need to use some content markup.